# Grouping Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have the following query:

```
SELECT od.product_id, od.product_name, od.product_quantity, od.product_price,
        o.id_address_delivery, a.id_country, a.id_state, s.name
FROM `ps_order_detail` od
LEFT JOIN ps_orders AS o ON od.`id_order` = o.`id_order`
LEFT JOIN `ps_address` AS a ON o.`id_address_delivery` = a.`id_address`
LEFT JOIN `ps_state` AS s ON a.id_state = s.id_state
ORDER BY o.`date_add` DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Where it returns data like the following :

product_id | product_name | product_qty | product_price | id_state

I'd like to know the best seller (in terms of quantity) on each state. For example:

State A : best seller is Product A (500 sold quantity)
State B : best seller is Product C (150 sold quantity)
State C : best seller is Product A (100 sold quantity)

At the moment i am thinking of doing a JOIN between 2 columns, but on second thought this requires a 'pivot' like features.

I know how to get the total sold quantity for each product

```
SELECT od.product_id, od.product_name, COUNT(od.product_id) AS 'total'
FROM `ps_order_detail` od
GROUP BY od.product_id
ORDER BY od.product_id DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

I also know the total sold quantity for each state, but i am not sure how to combine both to achive what i need. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Your group by will fail in 5.7 with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

Comment: @Drew it would fail in all MySQL version if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled :) The difference is that in the recent versions of 5.7 ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled by default, while in previous versions it is not. Although product_name is probably functionally dependent on product_id, so the latest versions of MySQL may even allow the query even if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled.

Comment: Right @Shadow out of the box. Of course it is configurable. 5.7 would be afterall loathe to disallow one to shoot themselves in the foot

Comment: Nay, MySQL just does not want everybody's code who learnt php / MySQL from Teach Yourself PHP in 24 Hours to break down after a migration :)

Comment: Yes i am using mysql 5.7, what would be the besr way to achieve this? Or is this something that should be done in code instead?

Answer (score 2):

You need the groupwise maximum of your aggregated query. You can do this e.g. like this:

```
select state, product_name, quantity
from (
  select id_state, state, product_id, product_name, quantity,
    @grprow := (case when @grp = id_state then @grprow + 1 else 1 end) as grprow,
    @grp := id_state
  from  ( 
    SELECT a.id_state, max(s.name) as state, od.product_id, 
         max(od.product_name) as product_name,
         sum(od.product_quantity) as quantity
    FROM `ps_order_detail` od
    LEFT JOIN ps_orders AS o ON od.`id_order` = o.`id_order`
    LEFT JOIN `ps_address` AS a ON o.`id_address_delivery` = a.`id_address`
    LEFT JOIN `ps_state` AS s ON a.id_state = s.id_state
    group by a.id_state, od.product_id
  ) grped,
  (select @grprow := 0, @grp := null) init
  order by id_state, quantity desc, product_id
) grpmax
where grprow = 1
order by id_state;
```

It will sum the quantities per state and product, then number the result per state, and then take the first one. If two products have the same quantity in a state, only one of them (with the lower product_id) is taken. If you would want to have both, you can adjust the numbering condition for `@grprow`.